# Extract well ordered xy coordinates of OpenCV's Canny Edge Detection in python

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates

I have a polygon like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Muj.png) and I'd like to get xy coordinates of the boundary of this polygon.

Therefore I tried a OpenCV's Canny Edge Detection and extracted the coordinates like this:

```
>>> edge = cv2.Canny(region, 100, 200)
>>> ans = []
>>> for y in range(0, edge.shape[0]):
>>>     for x in range(0, edge.shape[1]):
            if edge[y, x] != 0:
                ans = ans + [[x, y]]
>>> print ans
```

The problem is, that I'd like to extract the coordinates in an order like they are arranged in the boundary like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI5Vv.png) might explain.

As my polygons are complex, a convex hull did not work and because of the amount of the edge-points I get of cv2.edge() I need to use a fast algorithm.

Comment: You should use findContours instead of Canny

Comment: @Sunreef  Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the variable assignment is intended (y is assigned to x-axis and vice versa), but here I use to get certain coordinate:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('1.JPG')
edges = cv2.Canny(img,100,200)
ans = []
highestY = 0
highestX = 0
highestCoordinate = [0, 0]

for x in range(0, edges.shape[0]):
    for y in range(0, edges.shape[1]):
        if edges[x, y] != 0:            
            ans = ans + [[x, y]]
            if highestX < x:
                highestX = x
            if highestY < y:
                highestY = y
                highestCoordinate = [x, y]       

print(f"Highest y is {highestY}")
print(f"Highest x is {highestX}")
print(f"Highest coordinate is {highestCoordinate}")
```